# Removed HTML and Blade-Tags at the end of the file after made changes with PhpStorm

Tags: linux, laravel, git, phpstorm

I am working on a Lenovo ThinkPad L590 with Kubuntu 20.10 on it. For development, I am using PhpStorm and recognized a problem that I can not identify. After some UI changes in blade files (layout or text) the last 5 lines of code were gone. The result was a not properly working website layout. Went back to the files, fixed it and everything was ok. Two days later I had the same problem again.

We created a branch for testing purposes and found out that there is no problem with git checkout, git pull, or git push. So it could have something to do with my laptop but I am not able to recreate it.

I made a test with `smartmontools` and this is the result:

```
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       UMIS LENSE40512GMSP34MESTB3A
Serial Number:                      SS0L25153X3LC0170EBE
Firmware Version:                   2.3.7182
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1cc4
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x044a50
Total NVM Capacity:                 512.110.190.592 [512 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      6058
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512.110.190.592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            0
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            504a04 dd00000000
Local Time is:                      Mon Jun 28 10:47:35 2021 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x12):            1 Slot, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0016):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.50W    6.50W       -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.60W    4.60W       -    1  1  1  1        5       5
 2 +     3.90W    3.90W       -    2  2  2  2        5       5
 3 -     1.50W    1.50W       -    3  3  3  3     4000    4000
 4 -   0.0050W    0.50W       -    4  4  4  4    20000   30000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        34 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          3%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    8.471.227 [4,33 TB]
Data Units Written:                 11.246.530 [5,75 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 189.422.053
Host Write Commands:                164.508.932
Controller Busy Time:               46.444
Power Cycles:                       513
Power On Hours:                     1.513
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   100
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    61
Error Information Log Entries:      616
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               34 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

And I re-installed PhpStorm with the default plugins, changed the keymap from KDE to Windows, and increased the memory-heap from 2048 MB to 4096 MB.

Have someone experienced something like that?

Comment: Difficult to tell. The changes could possibly be caused by PhpStorm: either by running "Reformat" that removed the lines that IDE considered unused or by any other similar action that lead to this unfortunate bug. Are you able to reproduce this problem in this file by running Code > Reformat Code or Code > Optimize Imports?

Comment: Unfortunately it was not able to reproduce it. I selected some Blade files, made some changes and executed both actions.

Reformat Code: No lines changed: content is already properly formatted
Optimize Imports: 0 'use' statements checked, nothing was removed

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately there's too little details about the code & project to advise here. I would advise to contact us (PhpStorm team) directly next time this happens via Help " Contact Support.